# AWS Cognito Sync on React Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to use [aws cognito sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-sync.html) in my react native app?

There's no apparent support in the developer preview of [aws-sdk-react-native](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native/).

[react-native-aws-cognito-js](https://github.com/AirLabsTeam/react-native-aws-cognito-js/) seems to have once supported it, but now [no longer does](https://github.com/AirLabsTeam/react-native-aws-cognito-js/issues/2).

On my own, trying to use [amazon-cognito-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js), which is the Amazon Cognito Sync Manager for JavaScript, I've only been able to get a react native packager error:

```
Bundling `index.ios.js`  99.4% (316/317), failed.
error: bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module 'aws-sdk' from '.../testProject/node_modules/amazon-cognito-js/dist/amazon-cognito.min.js': Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:.../testProject/node_modules
```

I'm guessing this is a circular reference of some kind, deep in the npm rabbit hole. That approach doesn't seem like it should work anyway, though, since the repo's readme refers to the fact that it's designed for browsers, not for native devices:

> The library uses the browser's local storage API...

Is it currently possible for me to store data per-cognito-user in react-native?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like there have been developments, though not entirely useful yet: https://github.com/AirLabsTeam/react-native-aws-cognito-js/issues/2